# Undecidability of the language with its elements(TM) having empty language

Tags: turing-machines

We can write a decider for the language:

$E=\{A\; |\; A \mbox{ is a DFA and } L(A)=\emptyset\}$

by marking method.
 Why we cannot use the same method to write a decider for the language with TM as follows?

$A = \{ M \;|\; M \mbox{ is a TM and } L(M)=\emptyset\}$